# Android syncAdapter with Sqlite DB

Tags: sql, android-syncadapter

i want to sync the local db and server , if any data updated in server it should sync with android local db.

i have read the tutorial for syncAdapter from [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

but above link content provider is used, could any one share the details about how to use the sync Adapter with sq-lite DB. or please suggest me any good examples

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/handling-offline-capability-and-data-sync-in-an-android-app-part-2

Comment: have you found any example for this

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [stub content provider](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-stub-provider.html) and [custom sync adapter](https://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/). They have long text but very useful.